# pcolormesh with masked invalid values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a one-dimensional array as a pcolormesh (so the color varies along the x-axis, but is constant in the y-axis for each x). But my data has some bad values, so I'm using a masked array and a customized colormap with masked values set to blue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import copy

a = np.array([3, 5, 10, np.inf, 5, 8])
a = np.ma.masked_where(np.isinf(a), a)
imdata = np.vstack((a, a))
myhot = copy.copy(cm.hot)
myhot.set_bad('b', 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(imdata, cmap=myhot)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

It works fine if I don't have the `np.inf` value, but I just get a blank plot if I do. I seem to have misunderstood something about the way `set_bad` works because I get an additional warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  resdat /= (vmax - vmin)
```

What should I be doing to get the effect I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to mask `imdata`, not necessarily `a`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([3, 5, 10, np.inf, 5, 8])
imdata = np.ma.masked_invalid(np.atleast_2d(a))
cmap = plt.cm.hot
cmap.set_bad('b', 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(imdata, cmap=cmap)

plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you look at `imdata` in an interactive session, you'll see

```
In [185]: imdata
Out[185]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[  3.   5.  10.  inf   5.   8.]
 [  3.   5.  10.  inf   5.   8.]],
             mask =
 False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Above, `mask=False` means that nothing is masked. If you wrap that with `np.ma.masked_invalid` then:

```
In [186]: np.ma.masked_invalid(imdata)
Out[186]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[3.0 5.0 10.0 -- 5.0 8.0]
 [3.0 5.0 10.0 -- 5.0 8.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True False False]
 [False False False  True False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

The problem with masking `a` is that `np.vstack` does not respect the mask.
Alternatively, you could have used `np.ma.vstack`. Generally speaking, only
functions in the `np.ma` namespace respect the mask.

However, you don't actually need to use `vstack` here; `np.atleast_2d` will do.
`vstack` creates an array of shape `(2, N)`, while `np.atleast_2d` creates an array of shape `(1, N)`.

---

Another alternative is to use `set_over` instead of `set_bad`. This would allow
you to avoid needing a masked array altogether:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([3, 5, 10, np.inf, 5, 8])
imdata = np.atleast_2d(a)
cmap = plt.cm.hot
cmap.set_over('b')
cmap.set_under('g')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

b = a[np.isfinite(a)]
im = ax.pcolormesh(imdata, cmap=cmap, vmin=b.min(), vmax=b.max())

plt.colorbar(im, extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The [`extend='both'` in conjunction with `set_over`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27174118/190597) and `set_under` give you little colored arrows on the colorbar which indicate the color used for values beyond the colorbar's range.

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer: I've learned a lot from it!